# Multi-stage, multi-artefact deployment triggers in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

I have a release pipeline with 7 stages for 7 environments, each stage is exactly the same but it is mapped to deploy a different version of the same artefact which was built with environment variables. Is there a way to trigger a release when a specific artefact is built, and then only run the stage associated with that artefact?

At the moment, the functionality i'm seeing creates a release when the artefact is built and that triggers a deployment for all stages with "after release" in their deployment triggers, regardless of any filters that are also applied, i guess due to the fact that the associated artefact is still available, regardless of whether or not it is new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to trigger a release when a specific artefact is built, and then only run the stage associated with that artefact?

I am afraid there is no such way trigger a release when a specific artefact is built, and then only run the stage associated with that artefact.

That because there is no such option we could select the specific artefact as trigger, we could only select the Release artefact but could not select one artefact of Release artefact:

[image]

Besides, although your artifacts are same artefact, they are different versions, and each version corresponds to a separate stage, so in essence, **there is no close relationship between each stage and other stages. They correspond to their respective artefacts. Personally think that it is better to separate different stages into separate pipelines** and make our management clearer.